# mysql query problems, How to display values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

I faced with one problem. I have a code:

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'test', 'test123', 'testdb');


$sql = "
        SELECT g.id as groupId, g.name as groupName, d.device_id
        FROM librenms.devices as d
        INNER JOIN librenms.device_groups as g
                ON d.hostname LIKE  CONCAT('%', mysql.SPLIT_STR(g.pattern, '\"', 2), '%')
        WHERE g.pattern LIKE '_devices.hostname%'
        ORDER BY g.id
";


$qid = $mysqli->query($qry);

if($qid->num_rows == 0){
        die("no results from MySQL\n");
}else{
        while($row = $qid->fetch_object()){     // each row
                var_dump($row);
        }
}
```

Main thing is that this code find devices in database witch have the same "string" as devicegroups. And thats ok. But how can I print all the groups separately with devices which belongs which that group? Or how I can print even one group with devices which have same string between "".? Can any one can give some suggestions or smthng?

Comment: The '$row' is an array containing all the values returned by your query. So in your loop something like: echo "$row[groupId], $row[groupName]"\n;

Comment: As Kurt wrore fix this first: $qid = $mysqli->query($sql); then $row->groupId, $row->groupName, $row->device_id contains values from db

Comment: @user3741598 your way works with fetch_assoc function but Skyluk uses fetch_object function

Answer (score 1):

`$qid = $mysqli->query($qry);` should be `$qid = $mysqli->query($sql);`